# Apply openCV-python adaptive threshold to 3D tiff

Tags: python, opencv, adaptive-threshold, image-thresholding

I work with 3D volumes produced by confocal microscopy. These images have x,y,z dimensions around ~1024,1024,50 and are stored in a .tif file.

I want to apply OpenCV-python `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` to the whole image stack. The below code works well for a 2D image (1024,1024,1). How can I expand it for the whole volume and save the output .tif file?

```
img = cv2.imread("1024x1024x40.tif")
gimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gimg, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, -20)
cv2.imshow('original',img)
cv2.imshow('Adaptive threshold',th)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible solution :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886239/python-image-analysis-reading-a-multidimensional-tiff-file-from-confocal-micros

Answer (score 0):

### Using the [bioformats](https://pythonhosted.org/python-bioformats/) package:

I don't have test data but using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886239/python-image-analysis-reading-a-multidimensional-tiff-file-from-confocal-micros) as a guide, you might try something like the following:

```
import javabridge
import bioformats

javabridge.start_vm(class_path=bioformats.JARS)

path_to_data = '/path/to/data/file_name.tif'

xml_string = bioformats.get_omexml_metadata(path_to_data)
ome = bioformats.OMEXML(xml_string) # be sure everything is ascii
iome = ome.image(0) # e.g. first image

reader = bioformats.ImageReader(path_to_data)
raw_data = []
for z in range(iome.Pixels.get_SizeZ()):
    img = reader.read(z=z, series=0, rescale=False)
    gimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gimg, 255,
            cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, -20) 
    img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = th)
    raw_data.append(img)

bioformats.write_image("/path/to/data/file_name_OUTPUT.tif", raw_data)
```